# Detail view fails to display second time when launched from fiori launchpad

Tags: sapui5

I'm launching my ui5 application from fiori launchpad application.After launching the first time,when i go back to the launchpad and click on the tile again to display my ui5 application.I get this error for detail view while the master view is getting displayed-

```
2019-04-22 10:47:42.330000 adding element with duplicate id 'application-view-Display-component---detail--link1'
```

This error is coming from getFragment function but onExit i'm destroying the fragment everytime.

```
        _getFragment: function (sFragmentName) {
            var oFragment = this._Fragments[sFragmentName];
            if (oFragment) {
                return oFragment;
            }
            oFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), "bcdb.bcDemoBuyer.fragments." + sFragmentName, this);
            return this._Fragments[sFragmentName] = oFragment;
        }
```

Here is the onExit method in detailController

```
        onExit: function () {
            for (var sPropertyName in this._Fragments) {
                if (!this._Fragments.hasOwnProperty(sPropertyName)) {
                    return;
                }
                this._Fragments[sPropertyName].destroy();
                this._Fragments[sPropertyName] = null;
            }
        }
```

What is causing this error and how do i rectify this?

Comment: I'd suggest to debug the onExit method to see if what you want to destroy is really found and destroyed.

Comment: It is not being destroyed

Comment: The fragment is getting destroyed but an element inside is not

Comment: Seems some other object is referring to this element, you can try to destroy it manually.